# MySQL/PHP: Multiple AND/OR tags in SELECT from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables, `customer` and `reservations`. `customer` and `reservations` both contain a row called `customerID`. `reservations` contains two columns named resStart and resEnd that only have dates in them (YYYY-MM-DD, which is the exact format I'll be using to establish the $todaysdate variable.

I'd like to join those two to produce a table with single column of `customerID` along with other info, but only if $todaysdate falls on or between two dates. Note: $todaysdate is established elsewhere in my documents as either a _GET from url (ie. day.php?date=2012-07-04) or if none is established, today's date with date('Y-m-d'). This part of the code is not where my problems are lying, I'm sure of that. **I'm thinking it's a syntax error somewhere while defining the information in the mySql query.**

Here's what I'm working with. A little explanation: I'm wrapping PHP code around Javascript, and the goal here is to produce a separate DIV for each resStart. The Javascript is fetching offset variables to add to the CSS of each DIV, so each DIV is automatically placed relative to the equipment it's representing.

```
<?php
 $getreservations = mysql_query("
 SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN reservations WHERE ( customer.customerID = reservations.customerID ) 
 AND ($todaysdate = resStart OR $todaysdate >= resStart AND $todaysdate <= resEnd )
") 

or die(mysql_error());

while( false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getreservations)))
{
    $nameLast = $row["nameLast"];
    $nameFirst = $row["nameFirst"];
    $customerID = $row["customerID"];
    $equipID = $row["equipID"];
    $resStart = $row["resStart"];
    $resEnd = $row["resEnd"];
    $timeStart = $row["timeStart"];
    $timeEnd = $row["timeEnd"];
    $result =  strtotime($timeStart);
        $minute = date("i", $result );
        $second = date("s",$result );
        $hour = date("H", $result );

    if(true) {
 ?>
    <script language='javascript'>
    var left = $('#<?php echo("$hour$minute");?>').offset().left; 
    var top = $('#<?php echo $equipID;?>').offset().top; 

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<?php echo ("$customerID$equipID");?>).css( { 'left': (pos.left + width) + 'px', 'top': (pos.top + top) + 'px' } );     
}
    </script>

<?php } 
echo ("<div class='resContainer $customerID$equipID' id=$customerID$equipID>$nameLast, $nameFirst</div> ");

    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM customer c INNER JOIN reservations r USING(customerID) WHERE '{$todaysdate}' BETWEEN r.resStart AND r.resEnd
```

However, You can also get the "todaysdate" in SQL: `DATE(NOW())`, and the statement will be:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c INNER JOIN reservations r USING(customerID) WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN r.resStart AND r.resEnd
```

**EDIT**: added quotes around `$todaysdate` variable to avoid confusion

Comment: First, I had to drop the `c` and `r` and the `c.` and `r.`. I assume that it's some type of shorthand denotation but it's confusing me and furthermore, was not working on my server. 

Second, when querying SQL directly, obviously the $todaysdate variable isn't defined, and replacing it with a date (ie 2012-07-04)n returned an error. Adding quotations stopped the error (ie '2012-07-04')

I figured I'd leave those notes for anyone using this later for the same purposes. Otherwise this worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: Right, @BryanGuidicianni, `c` and `r` are shorthands (table aliases), if they are defined in query, you can no longer use the original table names, and must use the aliases only. Regarding the dates - you can do without quotes too - if you format the date without the dashes (just 20120704 as a number)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try your query directly in database first. You'll get proper error code and the information, where the problem is.
2. When using JOIN, you should specify the join condition, with USING or ON (table1.field=table2.field). (ref to doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN reservations  on customer.customerID = reservations.customerID 
WHERE curdate() BETWEEN r.resStart AND r.resEnd
```